# Result with number of days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DATETIME column in my table and I would like to know the number of days between the DATETIME value and now.

The query must be something like this:

```
SELECT *, DATESUBWHATEVER(datetimefield) AS days FROM table
```

Comment: `SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(), datefield) AS days FROM table`

Comment: Link to Manual with lots of date functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, datetimefield, NOW()) AS days from table;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEDIFF() function

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(DateTimeField,NOW()) FROM TABLE
```

DATEDIFF parameters explained:

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2)
```